# Is this an Observer Anti-Pattern? (with bonus state machine question)

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, observer-pattern, anti-patterns

I am wondering if the following is bad use of the Observer pattern. I know the Subject is supposed to be the one and the listener the many. However, I could end up with more subjects in my application than listeners!

### The Players

**Form1**: Self explanatory
**DocumentCreator**: Contains a Factory Method and a Strategy for picking a file from a list
**Document**: Contains information about the document file and a Template method for children

### Proposed

**IErrorProne**: interface for the above players to implement an event, turning them into subjects
**Reporting**: listens for IErrorProne objects and handles logging/emailing
**DocumentState**: This is a bonus that Im a bit iffy on. I havent quite settled on a good flow outside of the template. Currently I have a state machine inside the Document class. I want to pull the state machine out of the Document class and into Form1, decoupling the two from each other.

```
public interface IErrorProne
{
    public delegate void ErrorEventDelegate(
        object sender, 
        ErrorEventArgs e
        );

    public event ErrorEventDelegate ReportError;
}

public abstract class Document : IDisposable, IErrorProne // My Template
{
    public void Process()
    {
        //Error Occured
        OnReportError(); // safely triggers error reporting
    }
}

public class Reporting
{
    static Reporting instance = new Reporting();

    public void HandleError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e);
}

public partial class Form1 
{
    private DocumentCreator docFactory 
                                = new DocumentCreator(new RandomPicking());
    private Document theDoc     = null;
    private Reporting reporting = Reporting.Instance;
    private DocState state      = new InitialState(); 
    //DocState not in this example but demonstrates how it might work

    public Form1()
    {
        docFactory.ReportError += reporting.HandleError;
        theDoc.ReportError     += reporting.HandleError;

        docFactory.ReportError += state.HandleError;
        theDoc.ReportError     += state.HandleError;
    }

    void BackgroundWork(...)
    {
        using (theDoc = DocumentFactory.Instance.CreateDocument())
        {
           if (theDoc != null)
               theDoc.Process();
        }
    }
}
```

I guess my question is it an Anti-Pattern if I have a *Many to One*, rather than a *One to Many*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of it as publish-subscribe, then it really doesn't matter. If you take the Domain Event style, you can have anything and any number of things publish any given domain event, and anything and any number of things subscribe to domain events.

Many->Many, many->one, one->many are all valid.

Comment: Makes sense but can you expand "Domain Event Style". Also, any Ideas to integrate the state pattern? The issue is I cant think of an elegant way to make the State Machine Pattern and the Template Method Pattern to play nice.